# Implementing efficient cache system

Tags: android, caching

I am trying to implement cache system in my application. Let me give a bit of background first:

I have a view controller which requests data (these are different kind of forms) from Data Model. Data model returns data from Cache (on which this question is based) and if it is expired, it requests data from Server using REST web service.

To implement cache, I think I have two options:

1. Store data in serialized object when it arrives from server, and the send it to the controller whenever it needs it. The problem however is reading from memory everytime which may be expensive.
2. Create a proxy class which stores Static instance of data model class. The data model class will always have latest copy of data received from the server. This is faster but a bit complex and I would like to avoid it unless there is significant improvement in performance over the other option.

Any suggestion/example is really appreciated.

Regards,
Bsengar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement caching in android app for REST API results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746269/how-to-implement-caching-in-android-app-for-rest-api-results) see also [Is there an HttpClient that handles caching requests on its own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525496/is-there-an-httpclient-that-handles-caching-requests-on-its-own)

Comment: I think it is not duplicate, I forgot to mention one important bit, it should work well in offline mode. The solution mentioned there does not cover offline mode.